# Unable to call Snapshotter class from HttpServlet class

Tags: java, servlets, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to build a rest endpoint where user will pass `style.json` url and zxy values. According to the input I have to create a snapshot of that map tile.
If I use the mapbox's [Snapshotter](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/snapshotter/) in an activity I'm able to create snapshot. With HttpServlet I'm also able to get style and zxy But when I try to create snapshot from a class that extend HttpServlet I can't pass HttpServlet's context to snapshotter class.

Can Anyone please let me know what can I pass to snapshotter class in this case to take a map snapshot?

Here is a part of my httpservlet class's code

```
public final class TileRequest extends HttpServlet {  

    @Override
    public void service(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        Log.e("FileJson", " extend HttpServlet get called");

        File file = this.takeSnapshot();
        assert file != null;
        String url = NavDrawerMainActivity.getConnectionUtility().getUrl() + Constants.RequestConstants.REQUEST_GET_TILE_STR + file.getName();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("name", file.getName());
            jsonObject.put("url", url);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

In the `takeSnapshot();` method this the mapbox snapshotter class which take `Context` and as constructor agrument

```
MapSnapshotter mapSnapshotter = new MapSnapshotter(NavDrawerMainActivity.getmContext(), snapShotOptions);
```

I have tried TileRequest.this in `new MapSnapshotter` it does not accept that then I created a static context method in main activity and call it in `new MapSnapshotter` but it does not work with that too. It throws exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ThreadUtils isn't correctly initialised

Please let me know what to pass as context or how can I pass context to the snapshotter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to double check that the mapbox is initialized correctly.

```
Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.MapboxAccessToken);
```

In my case, I will instantiate it in the class that inherits Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.MapboxAccessToken);
    }
}
```